# T-SQL Why recursion dont stop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

Why this recursion don't stop?

```
DECLARE @T TABLE( id INT )
INSERT INTO @T( id ) VALUES (1), (2)

WITH cte AS(
    SELECT id, 1 a FROM @T WHERE id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T.id, O.id
    FROM @T T outer apply( SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.id = T.id ) O
    WHERE O.id IS NULL
    )
SELECT * FROM cte
```

If i use temp table #cte and will repeate recursive part - after some iterations will be 0 records...

Comment: @sagi ...which is [a well-known technique, recommended by Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx); I presume Alex is expecting the recursion to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

You start with a single row:

```
SELECT id, 1 a FROM @T WHERE id = 1  
1     1
```

1st recursion returns two rows (based on `CROSS APPLY`) and the `WHERE` removes one of them:

```
SELECT T.id, O.id
FROM @T T outer apply( SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.id = T.id ) O
WHERE O.id IS NULL

1     1     -- filtered
2     NULL  -- returned and used for next recursion
```

each following recursion returns two rows:

```
SELECT T.id, O.id
FROM @T T outer apply( SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.id = T.id ) O
WHERE O.id IS NULL

1     NULL  -- returned and used for next recursion
2     NULL  -- returned and used for next recursion
```

The result is correct, it's probably the logic you try to apply.

What are you actually trying to do? The query as-is is quite useless...

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this as a comment but I don't have sufficient reputation to do so.

The anchor member definition of your recursive CTE is correct. But not the recursive member definition. Since there will always be a record returned for the query

```
SELECT T.id, O.id
FROM @T T outer apply( SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.id = T.id ) O
WHERE O.id IS NULL
```

the recursion goes on forever.

Try WHERE O.id IS **NOT** NULL

For more information: [Recursive CTEs MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)